# TLS support in Flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ssl, https, air

I have an AIR desktop application that makes https call to certain APIs. This used to work correctly.

But after the [support for ssl was disabled by the Paypal API](https://devblog.paypal.com/poodle-ssl-3-0-vulnerability/), the calls are returning 2032 IOerror.

Here is the code snippet that makes the call:

```
            public var _service:HTTPService;

            this._service = new HTTPService();

            this._service.url = 'endpoint';

            this._service.resultFormat = "text";

            this._service.method = "POST";

            this._service.send();

            this._service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);

            this._service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultHandler);
```

Does flex support https calls using TLS protocol?

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Internet Explorer "Use TLS option" under Tools -> Internet Options  was unchecked. 
After enabling that option the calls are working fine.